# I want to edit html codes in Laravel script, unable to find html codes in (script/index.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change the "Add Listing" button text to "Post a Free Add" from the back-end of the script, but I am unable to find html codes from index.php file. I can see these html codes when I inspect the element from y browser. Can some one please help me in this case?(https://classifiedbazar.com/public/)

I tried to find the html codes in the File Manager Directory, but couldn't find it.

Comment: All the view file keep in the resource folder.  check it

Comment: `resources > view >`

Comment: First, find your route form route you can find controller function and which view is using by that URL , so after that, you have to find that view in resources -> views folder  their you can update your text

Comment: Thank you so much you safe my day!

Answer (score 1):

- Go to your laravel project directory.
- Then go to resources --->views directory.
- Now you can see .blade php file. Open and edit your html code with your editor.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you guys are best :)